# How do I buy Ethereum with USD - If I am citizen of not available in country in coin-base?

Tags: ether, exchanges, coinbase

In order to buy Ethereum currency I have followed this [How do I buy Ethereum with USD answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2071/4575):

But [coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/dashboard) does not allow me buy ETH since I am a Turkish citizen. Probably same issue occur for other countries, which I don't know the list.

**Occurred error:**

> Sorry! Buys not avaible in Turkey.

**[Q]** Does Kraken or Gemini allow Turkish citizen to buy ether? If not do you have an advice for me to follow?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: The "quick and dirty" is using [localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/country/TR) to get you BTC, then you go to [shapeshift](https://shapeshift.io/) and get ETH.

Comment: I dont dare to put this as an answer but: consider investing USD into buying mining hardware, find a cheap electricity provider and continue getting ETH via mining. This is potentially even more profitable than buying them.

Comment: Try using some proxy website and make your call from some other country's server.

Comment: Have you checked https://poloniex.com ?

Comment: They want authentication, so automatically they decline my citizenship. @Sanchit

Comment: Can't buy direct ether on poloniex. First I need to buy some BTC and convert on poleniex. @lalanv

Comment: Ask someone you trust located elsewhere to buy it for you... :-)

Comment: OMG I just googled _kraken turkey_! :'D ... I don't see why kraken should not accept Turkish citizen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/) accepts USD (Wire and SWIFT) and EUR (Wire and SEPA) and trades both ETH/USD and ETH/EUR pairs.

SEPA transfers are free, Wire costs $5 and SWIFT $10 fee.

Comment: Is single wire cost $5? @5chdn♦

Answer (score 2):

Can you buy BTC? A lot of users buy BTC to convert into ETH if they can't already purchase ETH in their country. You'll probably hit some more minimal charges, but it's definitely possible to do it this way.

Comment: Thats possible but I want to buy ether directly. @Chackle

Answer (score 0):

why not to try a VPN/proxy and change your location then use coinbase or other website. Besides, i've found https://changelly.com/ which accept Visa/master card

Comment: It says 200USD for 1 ETH. It cost double price. coinbase checks nationality with passport and identifies country based on that. @Badr Bellaj

Answer (score -1):

Try PandaBit, pax or CEX all accept debit card...

Comment: CEX takes high commission and sells ether $15 more expensive.@Stephen Richard Perrott