# A simple and direct way to buy ethereum without a broker/exchange?

Tags: ether

As a starter(day one) I find it very odd there apppears to be no simple direct way to buy ethereum. I dont want to an exchange/broker ' as i have had bad experience that was not resolved(reminds me of early paypal days when they would hold your money for infinity whilst 'so called' security checks were being performed lol. How do we keep the robber barons out of the crypto scene when centralized global banks for example;JP morgan itself is looking at the block chain tech for a centralised purpose. Interesting stuff. Please comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I buy Ethereum with USD?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/how-do-i-buy-ethereum-with-usd)

Comment: I would suggest this is completely 'On topic' and one of which many people would take into consideration, especially when its all supposedly about transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[localethereum](https://www.localethereum.com/) is in the making (currently ~80% done). It could be a more direct way to buy ether from someone else instead of going through an exchange.
Here in Vienna we have (afaik) a Ether/Bitcoin cash machine to buy Ether/Bitcoin directly with cash. But i've never used it, just heard about it.

Comment: One half sensible response thank you. I think i must have stepped on somebody's toes here regards dodgy exchanges. It reminds me of the early days of paypal that we have all happily forgotten, When they would just hold onto your cash for infinity and call it 'money laundering security check) thankfully they got whipped for that and are slightly more   coherent these days.

Comment: Thnks for a sensible response, sounds like you guys are on the project (: Local etherium sounds like what im thinking about, glad somebody could understand what i considered to be a rather simple question. An online simple interface portal is something i will have to wait for i guess. The broker interface is simnple enough but i would like the transaction  'closer to etherium' for reasons i have mentioned.

Comment: I'm eagerly waiting for localethereum aswell. But don't get me wrong, i'm in no way associated with the project @luminiferousEther.

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental fact to blockchain currencies is that they are decentralized. There is no central authority that owns, creates or issues Ether.

So, when you say "buy Ether", you mean exchange a certain amount of your currency of choice for a certain amount of Ether, but what should be the ratio? What is a fair market rate?

For that, you need to compare supply and demand, which is exactly what happens on the exchanges. They facilitate and broker the exchange process, and charge a fee for their services.

Of course, you are always free to track down a miner (or any holder of Ether) and make him an offer for his Ether against any goods, services or currency of your choice. That is absolutely a direct way to buy Ether that is available to you.

For most people, the most convenient way to do that is to use a broker.

Comment: Point A) yes it is decentralized, so what happens when centralized global banks get in on the act? The global banks aforementioned are as we speak implementing blockchain tech to incorporate crypto's. Now tthe dynamics have changed surely? Your last point is interesting, about tracking down a miner, a making a direct offer(to avoid fees/exchange) As i do not yet have ether is there a quick and easy way to do as you say? I am new to this game! If not somebody should make a simple transparent  interface to do this transaction from curenncy X to ether. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to have offline ethereum coins is to buy on exchange like coinbase and after that transfer all to your offline wallet. Simple enough.

Comment: Had bad encounters with coinbase never again.Hence my point. Why could the Author of etherium not set up a more 'direct to etherium' way to purchase it? It would provide a more secure platform and reduce fees and manipulation?